# Highcharts Dynamic Chart (Updating over certain interval) PHP+MySql Example

Tags: php, mysql, highcharts

I'm trying to use [**this**](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-update) demo to make it work with PHP & MySql so that after certain interval I get updated values from the database.

When I use

```
// using random value using javascript
setInterval(function() {
        var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
        var y = Math.random();
        series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
        }, 5000);
```

I get

[image: Normal chart]

But when I try putting an Ajax function like

```
var t;
setInterval(function() {
    var x = (new Date()).getTime(), // current time
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        url:'blahblah.php',
        success:function(data)
        {
             t = data;   // data will be a random numeric value
        }
    });        
    series.addPoint([x, t], true, true);
    }, 5000);
```

The chart turns into 
[image: Wrong chart]

#### blahblah.php

```
echo rand(10, 99);
```

I'm not able to determine why the line disappears on every ajax call. Also the plotting of the points is also not correct. The returned values are always greater than 10, but as you can see in the second chart, the plotting range is -2 to 8

I don't seem to find an appropriate mysql example to work with this kind  chart (auto updating after certain interval)

Are there any other alternatives to fetch data from the server and use that value inside the `setInterval` function?

Comment: I don't understand the problem/question.  if you're not getting the right values back from the server, you need to look at your sql and what the data being returned is.  Note that the posted example is meant to return and add a single data point to the chart, not replace the data with a new dataset...

Comment: I've corrected one issue (returning correct values from server side), but the lines still disappear and the only dots are shown on the chart and that too at random places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `series.addPoint([x, t], true, true);` inside success function - otherwise 't' will be undefined which will mess with chart.

Comment: `t` is defined outside `$.ajax`. So it should be within scope, shouldn't it? However, I'll try out your suggestion and see if that helps.

Comment: I figured it out. I had to `parseInt(t)`. Though I also had to shift `addPoint` inside success.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're always plotting the values in the same timestamp.
And make sure the value in 't' is numeric.

Comment: `t` is always numeric. But for some reason, using an `ajax` call is making the lines disappear.